how to disable the route `storage`
in a new laravel 11 project, if i run artisan route:list i also get the storage route:
GET|HEAD   storage/{path} ........... storage.local
the problem is that if i go to the url storage/private/file it downloads the specified file. even if in the private folder !!!
so i want, for my code to be able to store files but they should not be directly accessible from the web.
so basically i want to remove/disable the storage/ route
the docs does not seem to provide any info on that.

Did you try just overriding it ?

no, but if this is a default laravel route i should be able to disable it. there was a artisan command to link the storage folder, but not it seems is just linked!!

It is not a default route. You must have have written somewhere in your route file or some external library or package mush have created it.

so how to i find out where has it been created

php artisan route:list -v
or
php artisan route:list -vv command might help you find

Use php artisan route:list --except-vendor and php artisan route:list --only-vendor to find if route is created by vendor or not.

only vendor shows it. but i have only these dependencies    "php": "^8.2",
"google/apiclient": "^2.17.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.9",
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.9"
i still think it comes from laravel framework

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@memical, I think you can use .htaccess. This route allows direct download if necessary. You can also create another directory outside storage to store files (Keys).

i can disable access from web server, but i wanted to know why is it active in the first place

This is a recently added "route to enable temporary URLs on local disk in Storage".
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/52710/files
Private files will not be made public.
Assume that there is a file at storage/app/private/test.png.
If you look directly at http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/test.png, it will not be displayed.
If you use temporaryUrl(), it will be displayed for a certain period of time. It will not be made public unless you explicitly allow it.
<img src="{{ Storage::temporaryUrl('test.png', now()->addHour()) }}">

A URL like this is created.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/test.png?expires=***&signature=***
There is no problem, so you don't need to do anything.
If you really want to disable it, change serve in config/filesystems.php.
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
            'serve' => false,
            'throw' => false,
        ],


it has been made public, this is why i am trying to find out - why
